# Add divs between divs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working with a great jQuery plugin [(booklet)](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/), and pages of the booklet are defined as so:

```
<div id="mybook2">
    <div class="b-load">
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 1!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 2!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 3!</h3>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <h3>Yay, Page 4!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a div before each one of the pages (all the divs in div class="b-load").

How would I add it? .prepend? I'm not sure what to do here, I've never worked with jQuery or javascript at all, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is the jQuery manipulation documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)  It has everything you need to know about content manipulation.  The function you are looking for is `before`, as in `$('.b-load div').before('<div></div>')`

Comment: This worked perfectly after I put it in the right spot! Thanks! The link for the jQuery documentation should help me a lot, as well as the jsfiddle links below.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".b-load div").each(function(){
    $(this).prepend("<div></div>");
});
```

Should do the trick.

What this does is finds all the elements which matches ".b-load div" (".b-load, all child divs), and loops over them with a function. The function uses `$(this)` (which is the matched element) and prepends some markup to it, in this case `<div></div>`.

check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/SbwyX/)

Comment: It seems you're doubling your work here, jQuery applies these sorts of function to each matched element.

Comment: Yeah, very true. Perhaps that's why your correct answer has 4 votes and mine has a crappy 1.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link. It'll be very helpful for me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Give each div a class say, page and then you can use.

```
$('.page').each(function(){$(this).prepend('<div>Whatever</div')})
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
$('.b-load div').each(function(){$(this).prepend('<div>Whatever</div')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$('.b-load > div').before("<div></div>");
```

See http://api.jquery.com/before

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all of the children of `.b-load`, and use the `before` function to insert content before each one:

```
$(".b-load").children().each(function() {
   $(this).before("<div>New!</div>");
});
```

See an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/SbwyX/).

Comment: jQuery is the "write less do more" javascript framework.  There's no real need for the `each` here.  You can just call `before` on the children of `$('.b-load')`.

Comment: Mario was right. The jsfiddle is something that will helpful for me moving on, though. Thanks!